# populate dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to populate a drop down using JQuery but failing as I normally do, I can get the data to display in a Div but not in a drop down

I have a select id of name-data here is the JQuery code, what am I doing worng guys?

```
$('input#namein').on('change', function(){

    var name = $('input#namein').val();
    if ($.trim(name) != '') {
        $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, success = function(data) {

            var options = "";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";            
            }

            $("div#name-data").append(options);

        });


    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body> 
        Service user time Slots:
        <input type="text" id="namein" value="Name"> 
        Time Slots: 
        <form action="times" method=""> 
            <select id="name-data"></select> 
        </form> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/golabl1.js"></script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You need <select> , but you are targeting div in your selector?

Comment: Sorry I left that in when I was testing, I could get the output with  $("div#name-data").append(options); but not with  $("#name-data").append(options);

Comment: @PaulSmith that still doesn't address what `nevermind` was saying. Can we see your markup, please?

Comment: @Dropout yeah, here is the HTML I am playing with <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
 
 Service user time Slots: 
<input type="text" id="namein" value="Name">
            
            
            
           
 Time Slots: 
 <form action="times" method="">
  <select id="name-data">
   
 
  </select>
 
 
 
 
 </form> 
 
 
 
 
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/golabl1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: move the script tags inside the head

Comment: @Dropout when I do that the script does not run, it load the .js but when does fire the script

Comment: @PaulSmith the selector setup should be done prior to using it. Maybe on a `document.ready` event. Hold on.

Comment: @PaulSmith I've added an answer, could you try if it works for you, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers Guys go it, I used

$( document ).ready(function() {

```
console.log( "ready!" );

        $.post('ajax/name1.php', success = function(data) {
                if (data != ''){
$('#namein').append(data).show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to your HTML page :**

```
<select id="name-data"></select>
```

**And your JavaScript to this :**

```
var name = $('input#namein').val();if ($.trim(name) != '') {
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, success = function(data) {

        var options = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";            
        }

        document.getElementById('name-data').innerHTML = options;

    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like it is putting something in the dropdown now but its white space

Comment: Have you checked that data[i] definitely contains text? you can do `console.log(data[i]);` within the loop in order to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `script` tags into your head and then change markup for the selector to look like this:

```
<select id="name-data" disabled="disabled"></select>
```

so it's disabled until the values are loaded.Then change your code inside `js/golabl1.js` so it sets up the select right after the page finishes loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, success = function(data) {
        var options = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }
        var selector = document.getElementById('name-data');
        selector.innerHTML = options;
        selector.removeAttribute('disabled'); //enable the selector again
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok getting an output now but it is displaying funny, I will be getting back the words "morning", "lunch", "tea" but in the dropdown it is listing the word as individual  letters, here is a screen shot on what it looks like https://owncloud.fluency.net.uk/owncloud/index.php/s/YBfCTeGf4Bat6ws

Comment: try doing a `console.log(data)` inside of the post function's success block.. what does that give you?